# Do I get sliced for this case of passing derived classes into a function with base class reference arg?

Tags: c++

I have the following program

```
#include <iostream>

class Animal {
public:
    Animal(int age) : age_(age) {}
    virtual ~Animal() {}

    virtual void vocalize() = 0;
    virtual void description() = 0;
protected:
    int age_;
};

class Dog : public Animal {
public:
    Dog(int age, bool bites) : Animal(age), bites_(bites) {}
    virtual ~Dog() {}

    virtual void vocalize() {
        std::cout << "woff" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void description() {
        std::cout << "Dog" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "age " << age_ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "bites " << bites_ << std::endl;
    }
private:
    bool bites_;

};

class Cat : public Animal {
public:
    Cat(int age, bool likes_tuna) : Animal(age), likes_tuna_(likes_tuna) {}
    virtual ~Cat() {}

    virtual void vocalize() {
        std::cout << "meow" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void description() {
        std::cout << "Cat" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "age " << age_ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "likes tuna " << likes_tuna_ << std::endl;
    }
private:
    bool likes_tuna_;
};


int doStuff(Animal &animal) {
    animal.description();
    animal.vocalize();
}

int main() {
    Dog d(3, false);
    Cat c(5, true);

    doStuff(d);
    doStuff(c);
}
```

As you can see, when I invoke doStuff, I pass the derived class to bind to a base class reference, then invoke a method that is pure virtual, and reimplemented by each derived class. One of these methods (description), uses both member vars that are on the base class (age_) and vars that are on the derived class (likes_tuna_ and bites_). Am I getting sliced or is this legal? the program appears to work, but it might be by chance.

Comment: It's perfectly fine. You are not copying the object, just referencing it, so slicing can not happen.

Comment: @Daniel: Ok. I assume I can't access any member on the derived classes (e.g. an eatTuna() defined on Cat) unless I cast, which is probably not possible being a reference.

Comment: You can cast it. If you know what it really is use `static_cast` or use `dynamic_cast` (since your classes are virtual) and check the result of the cast.

Comment: @Daniel: doesn't dynamic_cast work only for pointers?

Comment: It also works on references, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).

Comment: @Daniel: Jolly good. Thanks!

Comment: One last comment: A `dynamic_cast` on a reference will throw an exception on failure. If you want to avoid it, turn the reference into a pointer and check the result against `NULL`: `Dog* dp = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(&animal)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I getting sliced or is this legal?

**No.** You are *not* getting slicing here.

Polymorphism requires either references or pointers, and in this case, you are using the former. That's fine. You are not passing arguments to your function by value, but by reference, which is what allows the reference to `Animal` (argument of `doStuff()`) to be bound to an object whose *actual* type is a subclass of `Animal`.

Slicing occurs when you attempt to *copy* an instance of a derived class onto an instance of a derived class:

```
Animal a; // Pretend Animal is not abstract...
Dog d;
a = d; // Slicing!
Animal& a1 = d; // No slicing!
Animal* pA = &d; // No slicing!
pA = &a1; // No slicing!
```

Comment: if I were to know the actual type of the passed object, can I recast the reference to the derived class? I think dynamic_cast works only on pointers, right?

Comment: @StefanoBorini: Yes. For instance: `Dog* pDog = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(&animal)`. `pDog` will be set to null if `animal` is not bound to an object of type `Dog`. If you are sure `animal` is bound to an instance of `Dog`, you could also use `static_cast` instead of `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @StefanoBorini `dynamic_cast` works on references as well as pointers.

Comment: @bames53: True, but if the runtime check for a `dynamic_cast` on a reference fails, it will throw an `std::bad_cast` exception, while a resulting pointer will just be set to `nullptr`.